# CSS from static folder in Django

Tags: python, css, django

my first question here. I'm still new to both Django and CSS.

I'm trying to use CSS from Static folder in my Django project. It's all at a pretty basic stage.

In the 'static' subfolder 'css' I have one main.css file with example code:

```
body{
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: black;
}

h1{
    color: #008000;
}
```

In my settings.py file I have:

```
import os
(...)
DEBUG = True
(...)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

And in my base.html template:

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Shopping List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST</h1>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried moving the css file, changing the view/url, and adding/deleting bootstrap (which alone works).

In the end my page just turns light blue-ish.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what help you want from us?

Comment: is your css file is not loading?

Comment: Yes, my css file is not working.

Comment: Yes, exactly, it does. I just posted it 10 minutes ago but it was deleted by the moderator.

Comment: That was because your answer was link-only... If you feel like your question is a duplicate of that question then please close-vote it as a duplicate instead of writing a link-only answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I checked your code and for me it works fine check if you have
**'django.contrib.staticfiles'** in your **INSTALLED_APPS**

If this didn't work I'm going to leave my code here, hope it helps.

```
-DjangoProject
    -static
       -css
         -testing.css
```

template.html

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="{% static 'css/testing.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',]

...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

I just noticed that my STATICFILES_DIRS is a tuple and not a list like in your example, I don't think it makes any difference but you could try it.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. I might try doing everything from scratch once again or using different environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but try removing the "/" before css in your html file:

...  href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">

Comment: Nope, that's not it.